# push menu left does't look good on iphone

Tags: html, css, menu, push, slide

Why my push left menu doesn't look good on iPhone and perhaps other mobile ?
I tested it on iMac, iPad it works fine, i think it doesn't look good under 768px.
someone have an idea ?

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

here is my link:

http://500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/news/zzz/index.html#

My Code:

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/font/font.css" />
        <link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            *, *:before, *:after {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="top">
        <div style="height: 100%;" id="container">
            <div style="height: 100%; width:100%; position:absolute;" id="o-wrapper" class="o-wrapper">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="leftcolumn">
                        <div style="margin-left: 0px;" id="c-button--push-left" class="c-button">MENU</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightcolumn"><a class="linkright" href="#top">TOP</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logocolumn"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="columnsContainer">
                    <div class="leftColumn">
                        <div style=" margin:0px auto; border:0px solid #fff; width:auto;">
                            <div class="lazy">
                                <img class="imgstylefirst" data-src="img/2.jpg" src="../../css/news/loading.gif" alt="" />
                                <br/>
                                <div class="creditstyleempty"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lazy">
                                <img class="imgstyle" data-src="img/3.jpg" src="../../css/news/loading.gif" alt="" />
                                <br/>
                                <div class="creditstyleempty"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lazy">
                                <img class="imgstyle" data-src="img/4.jpg" src="../../css/news/loading.gif" alt="" />
                                <div class="creditstylelast"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightColumn">
                        <div style="padding:70px 0px 50px 0px; margin: 0px 20px;"> <a href="#">Link 1</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Link 2</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Link 3</a>

                        </div>
                        <div style="margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;"> <span style="100%" class="newstitle">TITLE</span>

                            <p style="margin-top:-7px;">Blablabla</p>
                            <hr class="gridnews">
                            <div class="flipper">1</div>
                            <div style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px; display:block;" class="flip"> <span style="width:100%; height:auto;">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"  ...
          <br/><br/>
          <a href="#">Read more >></a>
          </span>

                            </div>
                            <div style="margin-top:20px; " class="flipper">2</div>
                            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">blabla</div>
                            <div style="margin-top:20px; " class="flipper">3</div>
                            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">blabla</div>
                            <div style="margin-top:20px; clear: left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav style="border-right:0.1em solid #404040;" id="c-menu--push-left" class="c-menu c-menu--push-left">
                <ul class="c-menu__items">
                    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">FRANCE<br/></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">AUSTRIA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">JAPAN</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">GERMANY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="c-menu__close">CLOSE</li>
                    <li style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; margin-left:10px; width: 90%; text-align:left; top: auto;" class="c-menu__item"> <span class="menufooter" style="font-size:9px; color:#fff;">©2011</span>
 <span style="font-size:8px; color:#fff; margin:0; padding:0;"> CANADA ALL RIGHTS RESERVED<br/>
    <a class="footerlinks" href="#">FRANCE</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="footerlinks" href="#">AUSTRIA</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="footerlinks" href="#">JAPAN</a>
    </span>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="c-mask" class="c-mask"></div>
        <script src="../../css/infinitescroll/jquery.unveil.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".lazy img").unveil(1000);
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/scrolltotop/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/scrolltotop/scrolltotop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/scrolltotop/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/scrolltotop/waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/scrolltotop/hidebacktotop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/menu/headerresize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/menu/menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/menu/menupush.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/news/readmore.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.content {
    max-width: 1260px;
    width: 90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:200px;
}
ul.c-menu__items {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
}
li.c-menu__item {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-40%);
    transform: translateY(-40%);
}
.c-button:hover {
    color:#e0ccb4;
}
a.c-menu__link:hover {
    color:#e0ccb4;
}
.c-button, .c-menu__close {
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    border-radius:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.c-button:focus, .c-menu__close:focus {
    outline:0
}
.c-mask, .c-menu {
    position:fixed;
}
.o-wrapper {
    transition:transform .3s
}
.c-menu, .o-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .3s;
}
.c-menu {
    z-index:200;
    background-color:#282828;
    transition:transform .3s;
}
.c-menu__items {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.c-menu--push-left {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden
}
.c-menu--push-left .c-menu__item {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
.c-menu--push-left .c-menu__item:first-child {
    border-top:none
}
.c-menu--push-left .c-menu__item:last-child:last-child {
    border-bottom:none
}
.c-menu--push-left .c-menu__link {
    display:block;
    padding-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
}
.c-menu--push-left .c-menu__close {
    display:block;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width:100%
}
.c-menu--push-left {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-100%);
    transform:translateX(-100%)
}
.c-menu--push-left.is-active {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
    -ms-transform:translateX(0);
    transform:translateX(0);
}
.c-mask, body.has-active-menu {
    overflow:hidden
}
.o-wrapper.has-push-left {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform:translateX(100%);
    transform:translateX(100%)
}
.c-mask {
    z-index:100;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    background-color:#282828;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .3s, width 0s .3s, height 0s .3s;
    transition:opacity .3s, width 0s .3s, height 0s .3s
}
.c-mask.is-active {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:.7;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .3s;
    transition:opacity .3s
}
/* media queries */
 @media all and (max-width:660px) {
    #carbonads {
        display:none
    }
}
@media all and (min-width:600px) {
    .c-menu__close {
        color:#fff;
        font-size:0px;
        height:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position:fixed
    }
    .c-menu--push-left {
        width:300px
    }
    .o-wrapper.has-push-left {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(300px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(300px);
        transform:translateX(300px)
    }
}
@media all and (max-width:600px) {
    c-menu__item, a.c-menu__link, .menufooter, .footerlinks {
        font-size:8px;
    }
    .c-menu__close {
        color:#fff;
        font-size:8px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display:none;
        position: fixed;
        top:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .c-menu__close:hover {
        color:#e0ccb4;
    }
    .c-menu--push-left {
        width:600px
    }
    .o-wrapper.has-push-left {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(600px);
        -ms-transform:translateX(600px);
        transform:translateX(600px)
    }
}
@media all and (max-height:480px) {
    c-menu__item, a.c-menu__link, .menufooter, .footerlinks {
        font-size:8px;
    }
    .c-menu__close {
        color:#fff;
        font-size:8px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display:none;
        position: fixed;
        top:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    li.c-menu__item {
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30%);
        transform: translateY(-30%);
    }
}
@media all and (max-height:300px) {
    li.c-menu__item {
        position: relative;
        top: 25%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-25%);
        transform: translateY(-25%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Include a screenshot of the problem. Also, include your CSS. Your HTML alone, with nothing else, doesn't really help.

Comment: well You are using very small fonts. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: my problem is visible on mobile i think, i tried it only on iPhone. if you can try to  open the menu on mobile, the result isn't the same than iMac screen when you resize it for example.  
as you can see on my screenshot, the font doesn't change, we can't see ©2011 canada all rights ... and you can see a scroll on the top right

Comment: do you have an idea  @BogdanKuštan